# Ошибка запрашиваемых прав доступа

Tags: android, kotlin

Столкнулась с проблемой. При нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" идёт проверка, есть ли права на сохранение файлов в директорию. При повторном запуске приложения и нажатия на кнопку оно вылетает с ошибкой "доступ запрещён", хотя при предыдущем запуске права подтверждались. Помогите разобраться. Обработчик нажатия прилагаю.

```
buttSave.setOnClickListener() {

            if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                val wb = Workbook()

                var i = 0
                while (i < tableLayout.childCount) {
                    val cell = wb.worksheets.get(0).cells.get(i + 1, 1)
                    cell.putValue(tableLayout.getChildAt(i))
                    i++
                }
                val currentDate = Date()
                val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy", Locale.getDefault())
                val dateText: String = dateFormat.format(currentDate)

                //wb.fileName= "$dateText.xls"
                wb.save("Workbook.xls")

                val file = File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                    ""
                )
                //sendEmail(file)
            }
            else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    PERMISSION_STORAGE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Там легче разобраться читая логи ошибок.

Comment: Как идёт получение permission status?